# connecting to Docker Hub in travis CI

Tags: docker, authentication, travis-ci

I tried to connect to my dockerHub via travis ci 
`echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin`
but i got this error 
`Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
docker login --username "$USER"  --password "$PWD"
```

Comment: How do you set the `USER` and `PWD` variables?  Is there some way to add secrets in Travis?

Comment: Never mind, I found that information here:  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-variables-in-repository-settings.  I'll leave it here in case it helps anyone :).  In case the link rots at some point in the future, you can click on a repository's Settings in Travis CI and add your secrets in the Environment Variables section.